# How can i use NVL function while i insert a value for null for a record

Tags: oracle

I have a scenario where i need to insert a value for NULL in a table. Can someone please help me as how i can do it. It's not only that am looking using NVL function but anything is appreciated.

Thanks,
Kumar

Comment: Can you please be more specific and show an example of what you mean?  To insert null in a column, you use the "NULL" keyword, no? The NVL function is to check if a value is null, and replace with some other value.

Comment: How are you inserting the data? Can you post your code?

Answer (score 1):

it sounds to me like you want `NVL2`

ie:

```
NVL2(your_var, 'val if not null', 'val if null')
```

or case/decode can also be used

eg:

```
SQL>   var a varchar2(11)
SQL> exec :a := 'not null';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select nvl2(:a, 'c', 'b') "nvl2",
  2         case when :a is null then 'b' else 'c' end "case",
  3         decode(:a, null, 'b', 'c') "decode"
  4    from dual;

n c d
- - -
c c c

SQL> exec :a := '';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select nvl2(:a, 'c', 'b') "nvl2",
  2         case when :a is null then 'b' else 'c' end "case",
  3         decode(:a, null, 'b', 'c') "decode"
  4    from dual;

n c d
- - -
b b b
```

so if you wanted the value as-is if not null, and something hard coded if its null then:

```
nvl2(age, age, 42)
```

so if `age` is null it goes to 42, otherwise it takes the value of `age`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Insert into mytable (ID, Name, Age) values (1,'John Smith', Null);
```

Comment: thanks for your response but in my case Age will not be Null always...If its defined, it need to get the right value and if its null, i will need to insert a specific value. So am wondering if this is possible.